# regular expressions to extract pages beguinning with the same url

Tags: python, regex, url, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like write a regular expression which allow me to extract  pages beguinning with the same url.

For example  :  I have the Following url

```
https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/soudan-le-president-dechu-en-prison-les-manifestants-toujours-mobilises-doc-1fp9z64
```

And want to only the url which beguin with :

```
https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/
```

so that i will have :

```
https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/le barça-est-gagnant
https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/mort au Zimbabwe
https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/le président français
```

So I tried

```
https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/*
https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/[^abc]*
```

It is not working I have to put the regular expression in a software which do the crawling , the software is written in python

Comment: why not just use `url.startswith("https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/")`

Comment: @wpercy Great answer. Post that as an answer and I'll +1 it. 'AT' kely789456123 are you trying to capture words separated by spaces that follow the URL?

Comment: @FailSale  yes some are , and others are seperated by "-" like in the first example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use something like:

```
import re

list = []

myStr = "https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/soudan-le-president-dechu-en-prison-les-manifestants-toujours-mobilises-doc-1fp9z64"
if "https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/" in myStr:
    list.append(myStr)
```

or use url.startswith() like the other commenter recommended.

Comment: Please remove that first answer. The second one is great. I'll +1 after you remove your first answer.

Comment: I removed the first

Answer (score 4):

You should just use [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) like this

```
if url.startswith('https://www.afp.com/fr/infos/334/'):
    # do stuff with url
```